# How to get Facebook friends' email?

Tags: facebook

Can I get a user's friends emails through Graph API? and How?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It doesn't appear that you can.

You can get a list of friends, but that only gives you ids and names.  It appears you have to get users to give you an access token to pull private info, such as email, on a per user basis.

- http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api
- http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user

Comment: There is no "public" email for API. You posted the link about user's fields, look there ;-)))

Comment: But  what is script for getting the list of  friends email

Answer (score 4):

Now we can notify our facebook friends by special emails:

```
facebook_username@facebook.com
```

Excellent feature)

Comment: This is actually a real good answer since, in my case as I'm sure in many, you want to send your friends an invite email rather than invite them through Facebook's notifications system—and this essentially allows for this.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot. You have to ask each user so he permit you to get his own email.

Comment: so how does yahoo allow you to import fb contacts?

Comment: @Amit: I don't use yahoo, so never seen its GUIs to do so.

Comment: @Amit Yahoo uses an application to retrieve the emails, not a fan page. That's the difference. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Unless the user's friends have made their email address public (which is highly unlikely) then no, you can't get a user's friend's email address.

Comment: email is always not-public for API. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You need to set scope paramter, eg: Set scope="email", which allows to get permit from user to access his EmailID, because by default you can access only id, name etc. So for this purpose, you need to get access from user.

Comment: can you give one example for this scope field because i don't know how to use scope field.

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't any way to get emails through API. But instead of that you can use profile username or profile ID to  login  or for other purposes.

Answer (score -3):

YES, of course you can.
All you want to have an email ID with YAHOO.
If you are having already then just sign-in
and go to the CONTACTS link on the left pane.
Now go to the ACTIONS link and click on IMPORT.
This will give you options to import your facebook contacts.
Just click on FACEBOOK, A pop-up window will appear.
Sign-in to facebook on that window.

It's DONE!!!
Enjoy.