# To get Facebook Friends email address

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get Facebook friends' email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331666/how-to-get-facebook-friends-email)

In my application i have to retrieve user's friends email address.I tried the following code,But i didn't get the friends email address.

My code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div> 
            <script> 
            window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                FB.init({
                  appId  : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                  status : true, // check login status
                  cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                  xfbml  : true,  // parse XFBML
          oauth  :true
                });

  function login(){


        /* Show User's Name*/ 


        FB.api('/me/friends', function(response) {
            alert("user name:"+response.name);
            alert("user mailid:"+response.email);
           // document.getElementById('login').style.display = "block";
           // document.getElementById('login').innerHTML = response.name + " succsessfully logged in!";
        });


    //window.location="http://google.com"; // Redirect to Another Page.

    }
```

But in the alert is not showing the mail id.I googled for this ,i found that email is not public property ,so what i can i do for retrieving the mail id.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know friend's email address is not accessible.

Thanks
Kaushik

Comment: Thanks Purusottam Kaushik..But is there any way (trick) to have that???

Comment: No Prakash not possible. You are talking about hacking into FB system. Which I will not recommend you to do. Why it is mandatory for you to get Friend's email address?

Comment: Purusottam Kaushik hacking is not my intention..In my application our requirement is that we have to send request to facebook friends by using their mail...thats y Purusottam Kaushik i am trying this..

Comment: Can you elaborate on the type of request. So that I can suggest you of an alternative approach.

Comment: S  Purusottam Kaushik i will explain..In my app,if user click option i have to get that user friends contact details(Either username or emailid).

Comment: Are you talking about their Facebook username? That’s easily accessible for friends of your current user.

Answer (score 1):

First Initialize FB Javascript SDK as following.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    // init the FB JS SDK
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID from the App Dashboard
      channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File for x-domain communication
      status     : true, // check the login status upon init?
      cookie     : true, // set sessions cookies to allow your server to access the session?
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML tags on this page?
    });

    // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here

  };

  // Load the SDK's source Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
</script>
```

The above code will initialize your FB SDK. Now in JavaScript write following function.
Refer [this document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) for more details.

```
function initiateFB Login()
{
 FB.login(function(response) {
   if (response.authResponse) 
   {
     //Login Success if you want you can initiate request for friend list here only.
     FB.api('/me/friends/fields=id,username', function(resp)
     {
       /// Process the resp over here. This resp will be JSON response of friend request
     }
     );
   }
   else 
   {
     console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
   }
 });

}
```

You can get the username i.e. FB User Name. Below is the request for that.

```
me/friends?fields=id,username
```

This request will give you a JSON response of following format.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "FB_ID", 
      "username": "FB_USER_NAME"
    }, 
    {
      "id": "FB_ID", 
      "username": "FB_USER_NAME"
    }
]
}
```

You can parse this and get the username.

Hope this helps.

Thanks

Kaushik

Comment: Thanks Purusottam Kaushik...Following url i used "https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?fields=id,username".....but it showing following error:{
   "error": {
      "message": "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 2500
   }
}

Comment: OK got you. Before making this request are you asking using user to login to FB in your application? Once you do that an access token will be assigned to your application and further FB Graph API call will be able to use it. As a side note once an access token is issued then it is valid for about 2 hours

Comment: Thanks  Purusottam Kaushik..I am new to this facebook concept..So can you tell how can i get the access token..if suppose i got access token,in the above url how can i use the access token..

Comment: OK... First you need to make user login to FB in your application. This will get an access token for your app. once the login is success then you can use FB.api to execute the request I mentioned let me modify the code to give you an example

Comment: I have modified my answer to show you the code.