# I want to fetch all the friends list from facebook by their email address?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get Facebook friends' email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331666/how-to-get-facebook-friends-email)

I want to fetch all the friends list from facebook. can any one lell me the way to get facebook friends list.i am developing a website, and i want there a option to invite my facebook frends by their email address.

Comment: possible dublicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331666/how-to-get-facebook-friends-email

Comment: So what do you tried.. There is no one here for completing your work..